# error : NIL issue - no such file or directory

Tags: image, go, pointers, hash

I've created an algo that does image hashing ( in order to delete doublons or images that are too similar ).
It works well when I apply it to a folder with less than 30 photos.

The problem is when the folder has more than 30 images.
At that moment, the algo returns that it can't find a specific image. But this image does exist, and when I delete this image, it tells me that another image does not exist this time. And so on, until it reaches less than 30 images.

```
2022/08/01 11:43:39 open TRYP_Madrid_Atocha_Hotel-002106a_hb_ro_035: no such file or directory
2022/08/01 11:43:39 invalid argument
panic: invalid argument

goroutine 1 [running]:
log.Panic({0xc000093e00?, 0x50dbe8?, 0x0?})
        /usr/local/go/src/log/log.go:385 +0x65
main.CompareImages({0xc0000e0000?, 0x1d?, 0x0?})
        /home/ivan/testing_go/output_images_madrid_TEST_2/hashing_image.go:110 +0x5b7
main.main()
        /home/ivan/testing_go/output_images_madrid_TEST_2/hashing_image.go:64 +0x207
exit status 2
```

I think that the problem is not related to the images but to the NIL (hence the NIL in the title)

Do you know what happens ?  And if yes, how to make the algo run for a file of more than 30 images ?

Thanks in advance

here is my code :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/corona10/goimagehash"
    "image/jpeg"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    directory := "./output_images_madrid_TEST_2"

    // Open the directory.
    outputDirRead, err := os.Open(directory)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    // Call Readdir to get all files.
    outputDirFiles, err := outputDirRead.Readdir(0)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    filesToAnalyse := []string{}
    // Loop over files.
    for outputIndex := range outputDirFiles {
        outputFileHere := outputDirFiles[outputIndex]

        // Get name of file.
        outputNameHere := outputFileHere.Name()
        filesToAnalyse = append(filesToAnalyse, outputNameHere)
        // Print name.
    }

res, err := CompareImages(filesToAnalyse)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(res)

    os.Exit(0)

}


func CompareImages(listImageFiles []string) ([]string, error) {
    var ListDebut []string
    var ListFin []string
    ListFin = listImageFiles
    IndexCheck := 0
    seuil := 20
    for IndexCheck < len(ListFin) {
        fmt.Println("=======================================")
        ListDebut = ListFin
        fmt.Println("INDEX CHECK + LISTFIN :: ", IndexCheck, ListFin)
        ListFin = []string{}
        for IndexSkip := 0; IndexSkip <= IndexCheck; IndexSkip++ {
            ListFin = append(ListFin, ListDebut[IndexSkip])
            fmt.Println("IMAGES TO SKIP :: ", ListFin)
        }
        file1, _ := os.Open(ListDebut[IndexCheck])
        IndexCheck += 1
        img1, _ := jpeg.Decode(file1) //TODO: Faire une function ici qui utilise le bon decode pour l'extension
        hash1, _ := goimagehash.AverageHash(img1)
        ElementToCompare := hash1
        for IndexCompare := IndexCheck; IndexCompare < len(ListDebut); IndexCompare++ {
            file2, err := os.Open(ListDebut[IndexCompare])
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
            }
            img2, err := jpeg.Decode(file2)
            if err != nil {
                log.Panic(err)
            }
            hash2, _ := goimagehash.AverageHash(img2)
            HashImageEnQuestion := hash2
            distance, err := ElementToCompare.Distance(HashImageEnQuestion)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
            }
            if distance >= seuil {
                ListFin = append(ListFin, ListDebut[IndexCompare])
            }
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("///////////// RETURN VALUE =======================================")
    fmt.Println("INDEX CHECK + LISTFIN :: ", IndexCheck, ListFin)
    return ListFin, nil
}
```

Comment: You open files, but never close them. If you have more than 30 files and apply this O(n^2) algorithm you'll open more than 900 times (40 files = 1600, 50 files = 2500, etc). Presumably you're running out of file descriptors. You'll want to close files when done reading them. Consider making a function that opens, reads, hashes, and closes a file, running that over all files, and then comparing just the hashes, too.

Comment: Note that you're also sometimes ignoring errors entirely, and sometimes printing something and then proceeding to use a nil value anyway. That's not good practice.

Comment: thx a lot !  I'm gonna do that, it was a rather obvious mistake it's true